# Map doesn't find entry by object key

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, ecmascript-5

I'm using a Map object when the key is an object, represented by an interface.
For some reason, the Map can't find the entry.

See my code:

```
export interface IMyObject
{
    property1 : string;
    property2 : number;
}
```

In my component:

```
MyMap : Map/*WeakMap*/<IMyObject, number[]> = new Map();

let key = { property1 : "AAA", property2: 1  } as IMyObject;
this.MyMap.set(key, [2,3,4,5]);
```

Depending on event handeler:

```
let mapKey = { property1: "AAA", property2: 1 } as IMyObject;
var A = this.MyMap.has(mapKey); //return false
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In general it works, you should look after your instance like: Is `this.MyMap` the desired variable and has the desired values. Maybe the map object get's cleared in the meantime.

Comment: No, I see the entries in it.

Comment: Using object as key, is a bad thing. your object key != mapKey. Both object has same property and value, but it's not the same object.

Comment: Objects are compared by reference. Are you sure you have the **same** object when checking existence. `console.log(new Map([[{}, 'There']]).has({}))`

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko - you are right - they are not the same, they have the same properties.

Comment: You cannot compare same key with new key object. Object reference defers for both. Check the below solution

Comment: @GuyE Unfortunately you can't override equality check for objects. So having them as keys is not that useful.

Comment: Thanks All !  I managed to solve it - stored the keys in a collection and take them out by their properties - solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It works when you say `this.MyMap.has(key)` instead of the newly created Object `mapKey`. This is probably because when creating an object in JavaScript it is stored with a specific memory id that is different between objects and `MyMap.has(...)` probably checks for that location/memory id and not if the object actually matches a key.
This is the same reason why you can"t compare objects with a simple equal operation.

```
const a = { prop1: "AAA", prop2: 1 };
const b = { prop1: "AAA", prop2: 1 };
console.log(a == b); //=> false
```

I would consider having objects as keys in a map a bad practice anyways, but YMMV.

To fix this problem you need to set a global object, add that to the map and only use that to check if the map has said object as a key.

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface IMyObject
{
    property1 : string;
    property2 : number;
}

let  MyMap  = new Map<IMyObject,number[]>();

let key = { property1 : "AAA", property2: 1  };
MyMap.set(key, [2,3,4,5]);

var b = MyMap.get(key); 
var A = MyMap.has(key); 
console.log(b);
console.log(A);
```